# Can I use both of my passports when I enter another country?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, dual-nationality, borders

I have two passports, from two different countries. I want to visit another country. I have visa valid for one month on one passport. When I arrive in the country I want to visit, is it possible to ask the border guards to put entry stamps in both passports?

Comment: Sure you can ask, but the likely consequences of your asking probably depend on the countries involved.  Can you tell us what they are?

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to do this?

Comment: I know some cases in which people have shown two passports.  However, in any case that I have seen, they have acquired a second citizenship and are returning to the country of their original citizenship.  They are travelling with their new nationality but also showing the passport of their original nationality.  There are sometimes reasons why this is useful.  Even in these cases, only one passport is stamped.  I have not seen a case in which two passports are shown and neither is that of the country being entered.

Comment: You need to pick one. You can show the other if asked, but you don't get to add the privileges accruing from one to those accruing from the other.

Answer (score 2):

You can travel with two passports, certainly; many dual nationals do so. However, as you seem to require a visa to enter the country you plan to visit, border officials may be unwilling to indicate your arrival on a second document.

If the alternate passport would allow you to enter visa free, why use the one that bears the visa? If a visa is required to use the alternate passport, why would they stamp it without one?

In truth, making such a request may expose you to unwanted scrutiny, or worse.